# Represent CIE 1931 color space

Tags: r, colors, lab-color-space

I have some XYZ coordinates that I want to represent in the CIE 1931 color space, like so:

[image: CIE color space diagram, source https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CIExy1931_MacAdam.png]

I need the diagrams but I couldn't find any possible way to represent it online or with R. Do you know how to do it or if it's even possible?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you want to do. If it is just achieving the appropriate color conversion you can use the `convertColor()` function already implemented in `R`. There is also a whole package on `Cran` [colorspace](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorspace/index.html) that allows you to do this and a lot more.

Comment: I already have the correct coordinates. I just want to plot them like this http://ej.iop.org/images/0022-3727/45/32/325105/Full/jphysd428223f05_online.jpg

Comment: Unless you provide the coordinates I suspect it will be hard to help you. There is however a little set of [slides](http://r2013-lyon.sciencesconf.org/file/42186) I remember that contains the code to plot chromaticity diagrams. The bare plotting code they used is provided on pp. 24-25.

Comment: See package [colorscience](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorscience/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package [pavo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pavo). More specifically, you're looking for the `cieplot()` function.

It's designed to work with specific S3 objects (results of the `colspace()`) but since you say you already have the coordinates, we'll have to work around it:

```r
# Generate a fake dataset
set.seed(20190320)
coldat <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n = 30, min = 0.15, max = 0.5), nrow = 10, ncol = 3))

# Make sure this dataset works with the cieplot() function
attr(coldat, "clrsp") <- "CIEXYZ"
colnames(coldat) <- c("x", "y", "z")

cieplot(coldat)
```

[image: result of cieplot() function]